# StarTeam not checking out to working folder?

Tags: starteam, vcs-checkout

I'm using StarTeam 4.1 and I'm trying to use the command line version of StarTeam to checkout all the files of the folder.  But for some reason, instead of checking out to C:\Installation, it checks out to C:\400\Installation.  In the GUI, StarTeam clearly states that the complete working folder path is C:\Installation.  If I run stcmd.exe and try to checkout a single file from the root of Installation, it says that there is no such file, while I can check it out from the GUI.  stcmd.exe also does not display all the subfolders of Installation.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realize that the view name was specified in the checkout command.  If you do not specify a view name, the default is used.  In my case, there was a folder named Installation and a view named Installation.  Since I just specified to checkout Installation, it was interpreted as a view name instead of a folder, and the Installation view  checked out the Installation folder to C:\400\Installation for some reason.